# Pip freeze not properly showing git dependency in venv

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I've pip installed some python packages from a git repository into a `venv` using the command:

`python -m pip install git+ssh://git@git.privateurl.com/repos/my-private-package.git`

Now, when i run `pip freeze`, the package appears like a 3rd party package like `my-private-package=0.2.1` rather than of the form:

`my-private-package @ git+ssh://git@git.privateurl.com/repos/my-private-package.git`

How can I force it to appear as the latter so that when i generate the `requirements.txt` it is easily shared to other colleagues who just have to run `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` ?

I've tried different python versions (3.6, 3.7, 3.8). I'm using the latest pip version (`21.1.2`) and I've tried Ubuntu and Mac and still reproduce the issue. The oddest thing is a colleague can run the same commands and get the right results.

Comment: Have you tried updating pip before running `pip freeze`? -- Probably related: [PEP 610](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0610/).

Comment: You mentioned your pip is up-to-date, I had not read this.

Comment: @Bananach no i didn't, i switched to using poetry for dependency management and it solved a lot of headaches

Comment: Has it solved the problem where you want to execute the same code in a different machine but don't want to wait half an hour for the installation to finish?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how/if `pip freeze` will do this, but you can use `pip-compile` (from the `pip-tools` package) to turn a requirements.in list with a git url into a requirement list that still has a git-url. The accompanying `pip-sync` will synchronize your virtualenv packages to those specified in the requirements list.

Answer (score -1):

There might be a problem with directory containing egg-info in the package you're trying to install. Try to delete it and then reinstall the package using `pip install -e`. It will create new directory with proper egg-info.